# FFmpeg Why is the drawbox filter breaking the crossfade and how can I get the desired result?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

In the code below, I'm adding various filters to each image.

To illustrate the issue, I have removed the `drawbox` filter from `[2:v]`.

Here is the video from teh code below: http://128.199.50.223/videos/super_user_test_10_temp.mp4

You will notice the the first transition cuts to black before the next image fades in. Then the second transition (from image 2 to image 3) crossfades. However, if i add the `drawbox` filter back into `[2:v]` it will cut to black and fade the second transition just like the first one.

So, my question has two parts:

1. Why is the drawbox breaking the crossfade and causing a cut to black before the fade in?
2. How can I get the translucent box behind the text while keeping the crossfade effect that is seen in the second transition?

Here is the Code:

```
ffmpeg \
-i images/25_test/31630738_0.jpg \
-i images/25_test/31630738_4.jpg \
-i images/25_test/31630738_6.jpg \
-i images/25_test/31630738_8.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=yuva420p, \
    scale=iw*10:ih*10, \
    zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=500:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480, \
    drawbox=y=0:color=black@0.6:width=iw:height=48:t=max, \
    drawtext='fontfile=fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf':text='Front':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=20:y=16, \
    fifo \
 [zoom_0]; \
 [1:v]format=yuva420p, \
    scale=iw*10:ih*10, \
    zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480, \
    drawbox=y=0:color=black@0.6:width=iw:height=48:t=max, \
    drawtext='fontfile=fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf':text='Kitchen':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=20:y=16, \
    fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1, \
    setpts=PTS+5/TB, \
    fifo \
 [zoom_1]; \
 [2:v]format=yuva420p, \
    scale=iw*10:ih*10, \
    zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480, \
    drawtext='fontfile=fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf':text='Entrance':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=20:y=16, \
    fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1, \
    setpts=PTS+10/TB, \
    fifo \
 [zoom_2]; \
 [3:v]format=yuva420p, \
    scale=iw*10:ih*10, \
    zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480, \
    drawbox=y=0:color=black@0.6:width=iw:height=48:t=max, \
    drawtext='fontfile=fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf':text='Pool':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=20:y=16, \
    fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1, \
    setpts=PTS+15/TB, \
    fifo \
 [zoom_3]; \
 [zoom_0][zoom_1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,15)'[overlay_0_1]; \
 [overlay_0_1][zoom_2]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,10,20)'[overlay_1_2]; \
 [overlay_1_2][zoom_3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,15,25)' \
" videos/out.mp4
```

Below is a simplified version that still shows the issue.
To test the code, input any 640x480 images.
You will see the cut, then fade.
Then remove the `drawbox` filters and you will see the crossfade as it should appear.

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 10 -i images/25_test/31630738_0.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 10 -i images/25_test/31630738_4.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=yuva420p, \
    drawbox=y=0:color=black@0.6:width=iw:height=48:t=max \
 [zoom_0]; \
 [1:v]format=yuva420p, \
    drawbox=y=0:color=black@0.6:width=iw:height=48:t=max, \
    fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1, \
    setpts=PTS+5/TB \
 [zoom_1]; \
 [zoom_0][zoom_1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,15)' \
" out.mp4
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine here. No black in between. Upgrade your ffmpeg. There was a bug related to text drawn on top of semi-transparent surfaces, which was fixed in Sep/Oct last year. I suspect this is related to that.

Comment: @Mulvya Do you see the difference between transition 1 and transition 2 ni the video I posted? Does your's look like the second transition? We are using `ffmpeg version 2.6.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)` What version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I get normal crossfades. Using a git version from last Monday.

Comment: @Mulvya could you please send a link to the git version you downloaded?

Comment: I compiled it but you can get one from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ Don't go for the 3.2.4 build.

Comment: @Mulvya We compiled a new version like this: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/var/www/html/FFmpeg-master/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I/var/www/html/FFmpeg-master/include" --extra-ldflags="-L/var/www/html/FFmpeg-master/lib" --bindir="/var/www/html/FFmpeg-master/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libfreetype --enable-pic --disable-yasm` it fixed the cross fade but now its running painfully slow. Do you have any suggestions for making it run faster

Comment: Remove `--disable-yasm`. That's like using `--enable-painfully-slow`. If you don't want to compile you can just download from http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks a lot! It's even faster than before! 
Would you please make an answer for me to mark correct. I'd like for you to get the credit for it.
Hopefully other people can see this and know to upgrade. We had the latest Debian version that we could find, but apparently it was pretty old.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is fine as-is. There was a bug in the drawtext filter due to which one could not draw text over a (semi-)transparent surface. Well, you could, but the alpha plane got reset to opaque. This bug was fixed in Sep 2016.